# filter a custom data type

Tags: haskell, recursion, filter

I have these data types

```
type Price = (Int, Int)
newtype PriceItem = PriceItem [(Price, PriceType)]
data PriceType = High
                | Medium
                | Low
                deriving Eq
```

and I'm trying to build a function that will give me a list with all the prices of a PriceItem (without the PriceType)

```
getPrices :: PriceItem -> [Price]
```

I can't find a way to make this function recursive, which it needs to be since there can be any number of tuples in the PriceItem list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `PriceItem` has a `[(Price, PriceType)]` in it. To turn a `(Price, PriceType)` into a `Price`, use `fst` to get the first element of the tuple. To do something to each element of a list, use `map`. Put those pieces together like this:

```
getPrices (PriceItem xs) = map fst xs
```

No explicit recursion is required.

---

If you wanted to write all of the involved functions (including the recursion) yourself, you could do this instead:

```
getPrices (PriceItem []) = []
getPrices (PriceItem ((price, _):xs)) = price:getPrices (PriceItem xs)
```